# IVP - Differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Working on this. Have to find a solution. Very new to DE:

$$\begin{cases}
 2yx'(y)-1=x^2(y) \\
 x(y=1)=1 \\
 \end{cases}
$$

Writing this as:

\begin{align}
2y \frac{dx}{dy}-1&=x^2y\\
\frac{1}{x^2}2y\,dx-1&=y\,dy\\
\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx &= 1+y\,dy\\
\int \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx &= \int 1+y\,dy\\
-\frac{1}{x}+C &= \frac{y^2}{2}+y+C
\end{align}

Is this correct? Feel like I'm just doing algebra, but don't really understand if it's correct. Would love feedback.

Comment: When you integrate both sides of an equation, only include an integration constant on one side.

Comment: Obviously, $x$ here is a function of $y$ and $x^2(y)$ is the less common variant of writing the square $x(y)^2=[x(y)]^2$. So you interpreted the equation incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ 2yx'(y)-1=x^2(y) \\$$
$$ 2y-y'=x^2y' $$
$$ 2y=y'(x^2+1) $$
This is separable:
$$2\int \dfrac {dx}{x^2+1}=\int \dfrac {dy}{y}$$
$$2 \arctan x =\ln y +C$$

Answer (score 1):

Careful, when you have $$2y \frac{dx}{dy}-1=x^2y$$ and divide both sides by $x^2$ you should get $$\frac{2y}{x^2}\frac{dx}{dy} - \frac{1}{x^2} = y$$ which is not the same as $$\frac{2y}{x^2}\frac{dx}{dy} - 1 = y.$$

Also, are you certain you've written the problem correctly?

Comment: Thank you for reply. That make sense. I divide the whole left side by x^2. Yes that should be the correct form of the problem..

Comment: @Claire21 I only ask because the solution involves lots of Bessel functions, which I wouldn't expect someone who's new to DEs to have seen before.  The equation as it's written is not separable.

Comment: Oh, ok. It should be a separable DE? At least those are the DE's we have been working with in class.. But ofcourse I could be wrong, Im very confused about this topic!

Comment: That would be my thought if you've been working with separable DE's in class. My guess is there's a typo either in the problem or in what you've typed, unless you're supposed to do something other than solve the DE.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't know if the teacher might made a mistake. It should be the correct one. I've added a parenthesis around the 'y', but don't think that changes anything...?

Comment: Ah! Yes, that makes a big difference.  As it was written before I was interpreting it as $x^2 \cdot y$ instead of $[x(y)]^2$.

Comment: I see, damn, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I have now tried this:

\begin{align}
2y \frac{dx}{dy}-1&=x^2y\\
\frac{1}{x^2}2y\,dx-\frac{1}{x^2}&=y\,dy\\
-x^{-2}+x^{-2}dx= \frac{y}{1}dy
\end{align}

Does this make sense..?